# How to fix "Error: Program type already present: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeListener"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, websocket, jetty

everytime I try to build and run my app I get 
Error: Program type already present: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeListener

I've already tried to exclude some groups and tried to remove every library

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "de.profi.obsstreamdeck"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:9.4.18.v20190429'
//implementation files('libs/gson-2.6.2.jar')
}
```

When I try to build and run the app on my emulator, I keep getting the error "Error: Program type already present: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeListener"

Comment: If you have more of the stacktrace that would help.  Please edit your question and include as much of the stacktrace as you can.